# Entire function which is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, constants

Give f is entire, I have to show if $$\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\text{Re }f(z)}{z}=0$$, then $f$ is bounded.

I've proved if $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{f(z)}z=0 $ then $f$ is constant by constructing  new function $g(z)$. But I really don't know how to define in my case or how to prove it. I've googled it and asked help from many one, but like me they also failed. Please provide a proper explanation in answer section rather comment. 
It would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tools are available to you? Harmonic functions? The Borel-Carathéodory inequality?

Comment: @Daniel sir, sorry I'm learning new sir. Borel-Caratheodory isn't known to me. But taylor series, Liouville's are available sir. Please sir I need a concrete solution, please explain in answer section

Comment: What about harmonic functions? If you got this exercise from Ahlfors, some facts about harmonic functions should be available.

Comment: @Daniel sir please give me a solution in answer section so that I could see what is actually requires.

Comment: @I've posted here for a solution, for a proper guide and help. So my earnest request please help me for this, I've struggled for so many times.

Comment: I don't get any informations from anywhere regarding this. A help would be great.

Comment: But to know what type of answer would be helpful to you, we must know a bit about your background. If you know a few things about harmonic functions, those would be convenient to use. So please tell us whether you know anything about harmonic functions.

Comment: @Daniel sir a bit about harmonic functions I know such as "real and imaginary part of a analytic function is harmonic",, "A harmonic function which is bounded in C is constant". Such types results I know.

Comment: Good. Also the Poisson integral formula (for harmonic functions on disks)?

Comment: No sir. Please answer using Taylor series, Liouville, harmonic functions etc, since I know only basics. Please sir.

Comment: As like I mentioned where I posted how to prove in case of f(z)/z, like this please prove this also.

Comment: Please sir provide a proof.

Comment: Please I need a attention for this. Please anyone help.

Comment: I've seen Ahlfors, but can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n.$ Let $u$ be the real part of $f.$ Then

$$\tag 1 u(z) = \frac{f(z)+\overline {f(z)}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left (a_0 + \overline {a_0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline {a_n}\cdot\overline {z}^n\right ).$$

Setting  $z=re^{it}$ in $(1)$ gives a nice Fourier series for $u.$ Apply Parseval to this, using the orthogonality of the exponentials and $|u(re^{it})|= o(r)$ as $r\to \infty.$

Comment: I'm new in complex analysis, I eant explicit answer, please give explicit answer also I'm unable to get your answer.

Comment: Also I don't have knowledge for fourier series much.